# I get an error when I use react-native-countdown-component

Tags: react-native, countdown

I use the `react-native-countdown-component` package in my project. Everything is okay, but when I call a function on `onFinish` I get an error.

here is my code

```xml
<CountDown
  until={exam.staringRemainingTime}
  size={18}
  onFinish={() => getExam()}
  digitStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}
  digitTxtStyle={{color: '#1CC625'}}
  timeToShow={['D', 'H', 'M', 'S']}
  timeLabels={{d: 'DD', h: 'HH', m: 'MM', s: 'SS'}}
  running={timerIsActive}
/>
```

Here is error

```
TypeError: _reactNative.AppState.removeEventListener is not a function (it is undefined)
```

I use functional component

Comment: `react-native-countdown-component` is no longer maintained. Use [react-native-countdown-fixed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-fixed) instead.

Comment: It's working. Thank you @kiuQ